# How to make a horizontal always maintain its background colour, even when scrolled along the X axis?

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar

I am using a header `div` at the top of every page on my website. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ef91trf3/). The header has a width of 100%, which works fine, as long as the text isn't zoomed up to a point it must wrap and overflow the header, therefore forcing the page to add a horizontal scrollbar. When this is scrolled, the background colour of the header is lost, as the text is overflowing and the header isn't dynamically sticking to the 100% width of the page.

[Here is a visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzyOL.png).

One thing I've noticed is that on especially Stack Exchange sites (excluding Stack Overflow, as that header is `position: fixed`) and Atlassain's BitBucket, when you zoom up to the header, it presents you with a horizontal scrollbar, and when scrolled, the header background colour remains ([visual example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEyUV.png)). How can I achieve this effect on my website (I do not want to apply `overflow-x: auto` to my header, as the horizontal scrollbar looks rather ugly on that single element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If display attribute is set to table then it works for me.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;

    background-color: #161616; /* Fallback for browsers that don't support background gradients */

    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#3b3b3b, #2f2f2f); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(#3b3b3b, #2f2f2f); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(#3b3b3b, #2f2f2f); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: radial-gradient(#3b3b3b, #2f2f2f); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */

    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
}

.subtitle {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    font-size: 1.2px;
}

.fullWidth {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(141, 141, 141, 0.5);
}

.fullWidth .inner {
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="fullWidth" style="display: table;">
  <div class="inner">
    <div style="display: table;">

      <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/194077/Placeholder.png" style="width: 100px;" />
      </div>

      <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 2;">
        <div class="title">The problematic header</div>
        <div class="subtitle">Try making the result frame have a low width, then scroll the frame horizontally</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
<div style="padding: 10px;">
    Notice how the background colour of the .fullWidth div is lost!<br />
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/yCxIT2X.png">http://i.imgur.com/yCxIT2X.png</a>
</div>
</body>
```